# ASP.net Forms authentication not working on iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

i working on windowsbased authentication my config looks like this

web.config

authorization

allow roles="Administrator"

allow roles="SuperUser" />

deny users="*"

authorization

in global.asax.cs

```
    void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            message = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + " login successfully !";
        else
            message = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress + " login failure !";             
    }
```

this works perfect in cassini. i am able to login to the application.

when i host it in IIS 7 with windows Authentication enabled.

i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is because for some reason HttpContext.Current.User is null

for some reason the user is not set in the httpcontext.

please help me to solve this

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed pipeline in iis apppool is set to Integrated.
with this one turned on the httpcontext is not set on Application_AuthenticateRequest event.
this is little bit premature to access the httpcontext.

so i moved the logic to the appropriate place inside my landing controller method and it worked.

Thanks.